# A better way of constructing the query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

**Input :**

`Month, Year, GraceMonth.` All are in Integer.

**What we need to do ?**

First need to construct the date from Month, Year and Day(need to get from the current date)
and then add GraceMonth to it.We will get the new Date obviously after adding the GraceMonth.
Next, from the date constructed, we need to compare that with the current date.

**What have you tried?**

e.g. ( I am showing in Parts)

```
DECLARE @Month INT = 11
DECLARE @YEAR INT = 2012
DECLARE @Graceperiod INT = 2 

SELECT 
    [Construct Initial Date] = DATEADD(mm, (@YEAR - 1900) * 12 + @Month - 1 , DAY(GETDATE()) - 1) --construct initial date  
    ,[Add Grace period] =DATEADD(mm,@Graceperiod,DATEADD(mm, (@YEAR - 1900) * 12 + @Month - 1 , DAY(GETDATE()) - 1)) --add grace month
    ,[DateDiff] = DATEDIFF
            (
                DAY,
                DATEADD(mm, (@YEAR - 1900) * 12 + (@Month + @Graceperiod) - 1 , DAY(GETDATE()) - 1),
                GETDATE()
             ) -- datediff
```

**Result**

```
Construct Initial Date        Add Grace period              DateDiff
2012-11-14 00:00:00.000       2013-01-14 00:00:00.000      -122
```

**If your answer is correct, then what are you looking for?**

Is there any other good approach apart from this? The more concise without Casting, the better. And please provide explanation if it involves some tricky part (e.g. some tricky mathematical calculation).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first observation is - why not add `@Month` and `@Graceperiod` together, rather than doing two separate `DATEADD(month...` calls with them?

Comment: Sir, I updated that in the [Datediff] column by following your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Month INT = 11
DECLARE @YEAR INT = 2012
DECLARE @Graceperiod INT = 2 

SELECT 
      [Construct Date] = DATEADD(mm, (@YEAR - 1900) * 12 + @Month - 1 , DAY(GETDATE()) - 1) --construct date
      ,[Add Grace period] =DATEADD(mm,@Graceperiod,DATEADD(mm, (@YEAR - 1900) * 12 + @Month - 1 , DAY(GETDATE()) - 1)) --add grace month
      ,[DateDiff] = DATEDIFF(
                        DAY,
                        DATEADD(mm,@Graceperiod,DATEADD(mm, (@YEAR - 1900) * 12 + @Month - 1 , DAY(GETDATE()) - 1)),
                        GETDATE()
                  ) -- datediff
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
DECLARE @Month INT = 11
DECLARE @YEAR INT = 2012
DECLARE @Graceperiod INT = 2 

SELECT DATEADD(mm,(@month-month(getdate())),DATEADD(year,@year-YEAR(getdate()),getdate())) as InitialDate,
       DATEADD(mm,@Graceperiod,DATEADD(mm,(@month-month(getdate())),DATEADD(year,@year-YEAR(getdate()),getdate()))) as GraceDate,
       DATEDIFF(day,DATEADD(mm,@Graceperiod,DATEADD(mm,(@month-month(getdate())),DATEADD(year,@year-YEAR(getdate()),getdate()))),GETDATE()) as DateDiffs
```

Comment: Sir, can you provide the solution without casting

Answer (score 1):

try this:

This may not give any performance improvement i think, but reduces little bit of your code

```
DECLARE @Month INT = 11
DECLARE @YEAR INT = 2012
DECLARE @Graceperiod INT = 2 

;with cte as   (select DATEADD(mm, (@YEAR - 1900) * 12 + @Month - 1 ,0) as begining_month)
 select DATEADD(dd,DAY(GETDATE()) - 1,begining_month) as [Construct Initial Date],
        DATEADD(mm,@Graceperiod,DATEADD(dd,DAY(GETDATE()) - 1,begining_month)) as [Add Grace period] ,
        DATEDIFF(DAY,DATEADD(mm,@Graceperiod,DATEADD(dd,DAY(GETDATE()) - 1,begining_month)), GETDATE()) as [DateDiff]
 from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

You were doing same calculation three times, Try this to save that

```
DECLARE @Month INT = 11
DECLARE @YEAR INT = 2012
DECLARE @Graceperiod INT = 2 

-- This is that calculation
DECLARE @ConstructInitialDate DATETIME = DATEADD(mm, (@YEAR - 1900) * 12 + @Month - 1 , DAY(GETDATE()) - 1)

SELECT 
    [Construct Initial Date] = @ConstructInitialDate --construct initial date  
    ,[Add Grace period] =DATEADD(mm, @Graceperiod, @ConstructInitialDate) --add grace month
    ,[DateDiff] = DATEDIFF
(
   DAY,
   DATEADD(mm,@Graceperiod, @ConstructInitialDate),
   GETDATE()
)
```

Comment: The focus is only on the [DateDiff] field and not on the other fields. The other fields I displayed  only to show step by step as how I have solved the problem.